# I just installed QT for Windows but I can't find the control toolbox anywhere. Where do I drag controls to a form?

Tags: python, qt, qt4

I opened a starter application to see how it works but I only see C++ files, nothing in Python. How can I configure QT to work for Python? :S

Also, where can I find the visual form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python support see [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt).

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "visual form".

Answer (score 1):

Qt comes with Qt Designer which you can use to create forms visually (like in Visual Studio). Designer creates XML ".ui" files that are then fed into Qt's UIC tool. That tool then generates C++ header files that define a class with the UI components. PyQt also provides ways to generate Python code from the ".ui" files.

Qt Creator has the Designer embedded, but it will be difficult to use that one with PyQt.